# Is there an existing XSLT to transform XML to a Perl eval()-friendly format?

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I'm in a environment with *very* limited options in terms of loading Perl libraries, and we have this recurring need to parse simple XML, without the usual XML libraries available to us.

I occurred to me that one solution could be to transform the XML in to an eval() friendly format.

In the interests of not reinventing the wheel, does anyone know of an existing XSL template to do that?

Comment: How limited is very limited? Are the JSON and YAML libraries off-limits?

Comment: Adding a library is a multi-month process. Looking at the base system, I don't have either JSON on YAML for Perl.

Comment: Inline XML::TreePP (Pure Perl implementation for parsing/writing XML documents) into the top of your script with App::FatPacker (pack your dependencies onto your script file).  Install those modules into your development environment, or create a temporary local::lib installation just for this purpose and remove it.

Comment: JSON::PP is in Perl core after 5.13.9 (5.14) so it is time to upgrade.  Also Parse::CPAN::Meta (core since 5.10.1) is YAML::Tiny in disguise.

Comment: From a theoretical standpoint I find this very interesting. However simply `eval`ing stuff may potentially open security holes. Just look at JavaScript/JSON.

Answer (score -2):

XML is a rather simple format. It's easy to implement using a few regex. [Starting point](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=893908). Take a peek at my second reply to that post for some things it doesn't handle.

Comment: For something that handles a lot of things that are on ikegami's "can't handle" list, see MKDoc::XML::Tokenizer and the rest of MKDoc::XML.